# Lua error -129 for most mediawiki templates

Tags: lua, mediawiki, wiki

I've been attempting to import some wikipedia templates in my local mediawiki wiki, but most attempts at using them end up with the same error. For instance, for the following code :

```
==Title==
{{Main|Title}}
```

(which uses the [main template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Main)), I get the following error :

```
Lua error: Internal error: The interpreter has terminated with signal "-129".

No further details are available.
```

I haven't been able to find any occurence of that error, or even a relevant use of 129 in the source code I could find, and there is nothing generated in the Lua error log.

The Lua binaries have all been given permission to be executed, and I have installed the Scribunto and TemplateStyles extensions and a variety of modules, although beyond the ones advised for main, I don't know where to find a list of missing modules if there are any.

Edit : Here is the output of $status in Scribunto :

```
array(8) { 
    ["command"]=> string(459) "'exec' '/bin/sh' '/XXX/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/lua_ulimit.sh' '7' '8' '51200' ''\''/XXX/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/lua5_1_5_linux_32_generic/lua'\'' '\''/XXX/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/mw_main.lua'\'' '\''/XXX/extensions/Scribunto/includes'\'' '\''0'\'' '\''4'\'''" 
    ["pid"]=> int(17067) 
    ["running"]=> bool(false) 
    ["signaled"]=> bool(true) 
    ["stopped"]=> bool(false) 
    ["exitcode"]=> int(-1) 
    ["termsig"]=> int(-129) 
    ["stopsig"]=> int(0) 
    }
```

I am beginning to suspect that the issue may be that my server doesn't allow executables.

Comment: The error code is calculated, That's why you don't find -129 in the source code. searching for the message brings you to a localization json file which then brings you here: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Scribunto/blob/fda6a663aa36b20b59f1f47e8514c3f1dda14184/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/LuaStandaloneInterpreter.php#L654

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: The wiki is on a remote server, on Debian 8.11

Comment: "I am beginning to suspect that the issue may be that my server doesn't allow executables." That would definitely be consistent with what you're seeing. You should try a simple PHP script and a simple executable of your own to test that theory.